# Add the Form name to the theme suggestions input field

Tags: theming, 8

How do I get the form name to the theme a suggestion input in Drupal 8?

```
function [THEME_NAME]_theme_suggestions_input_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if (isset($variables['element']['#parents'])) {
    $suggestions[] = 'input__'.$variables['element']['#parents'][0] ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

In your `yourTheme.theme`, you could do:

```
function yourTheme_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  foreach (\Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children($form) as $key) {
    $form[$key]['#attributes']['data-twig-suggestion'] = $form['#id'];
  }

  $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['data-twig-suggestion'] = $form['#id'];
}
```

The function `\Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children($form)` returns an array of all the children elements (for a form) for which the keys don't start with `#`.

So, this array will have the field names as its elements. Then, you iterate over the array and add the attribute `data-twig-suggestion` and its corresponding value. Note that the array will have some extra elements that aren't form fields, and those would also get the new attribute and its value. I don't think there is any collateral damage on that.

For the submit button (`$form['actions']['submit']`) we are adding the attribute "manually", as the field element (`submit`) is "nested" inside the `actions` array, so our previous loop won't have added the attribute to the correct element in the array.

Then, you also add this function:

```
function yourTheme_theme_suggestions_input_alter(&$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if (isset($element['#attributes']['data-twig-suggestion'])) {
    $suggestion_suffix = str_replace(['-'], '_', $element['#attributes']['data-twig-suggestion']);
    $suggestions[] = 'input__' . $element['#type'] . '__' . $suggestion_suffix;
  }
}
```

Here, each form input field is processed and a template suggestion is added based on the previously created attribute.

PS: this solution is based on this article: [Getting granular with Drupal 8 forms](https://yellowpencil.com/blog/getting-granular-with-drupal-eight-forms/).

Comment: This answer is awesome.  If you need a little more Juice,  give https://www.drupal.org/project/themable_forms a try,  which will add template suggestions not just to inputs, but also to the form-element.html.twig, you could also just copy the code to your theme: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/themable_forms/blob/8.x-1.x/themable_forms.module

Answer (score 0):

The [Formdazzle!](https://www.drupal.org/project/formdazzle) module does exactly that.

> Theming drupal forms can be difficult and time-consuming. This module
>   provides a set of utilities that make form theming easier.
>
> Currently, this module provides theme suggestions for forms that are
>   much more useful than those provided by Drupal core.
>
> - Theme suggestions for all form elements (including buttons)
> - Theme suggestions for all form element labels
> - All theme suggestions include the form ID and the form element name; e.g. `[element-type]--[form-id]--[form-element-name].html.twig`